# flac codec, 2 files, same duration, but different memory sizes

Tags: audio, memory, ffmpeg, mp4, flac

So I have 2 audio flac files converted from mp4 files. Both are 31 seconds long but one is of 1MB and the other one comes out to be of 4MB. Well, I am using ffmpeg with 8000 sample rate in exactly the same manner. Can anyone explain why this could be happening ?

Is there any particular way in which the mp4 source file has to be coded ? or any other pointers please ?

Thanks already, 
asmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flac files are compressed using lossless compression so the output file size depends on how well that compression works on a particular file. So even for input with the same duration you would expect the output size to vary.

It is only if you were producing uncompressed output (such as a Wav file) that you would expect the sizes to be the same.